# Boolean filter geopandas dataframe following shapely within

Tags: pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have a geopandas dataframe I perform a convexhull operation on a multipoint dataset using shapely.

```
top_sample_col.within(cvh_base)
```

This returns a boolean, how do I assign to a new gdf only those that are assigned true? (option A)

I can use `.set_index()` but then how do I filter by the index=True (option B)

Option A is the preferred method.

Edit

This does the job, but can it be more streamlined?

```
df['within'] = top_sample_col.within(cvh_base)
df = df.loc[df['within'] == True]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the boolean array as a mask directly.

```py
df = df.loc[top_sample_col.within(cvh_base)]
```